# How to make a regex for decimal that has a defined length (comma included)

Tags: java, regex

I am looking for a 15 characters length regex with a decimal.
In the swift documentation, the regex would look like this : 3!a15d where 3!a means [a-zA-Z]{3} and 15d means a decimal of 15 characters length with a comma.

I tried the regex below :

```
([A-Z]{3}[0-9]{1,14}[,][0-9]{1})|([A-Z]{3}[0-9]{1,13}[,][0-9]{1,2})|([0-9]{1,12}[,][0-9]{1,3})|([0-9]{1,11}[,][0-9]{1,4})|([0-9]{1,10}[,][0-9]{1,5})|([0-9]{1,9}[,][0-9]{1,6})|([0-9]{1,8}[,][0-9]{1,7})|([0-9]{1,7}[,][0-9]{1,8})|([0-9]{1,6}[,][0-9]{1,9})|([0-9]{1,5}[,][0-9]{1,10})|([0-9]{1,4}[,][0-9]{1,11})|([0-9]{1,3}[,][0-9]{1,12})|([0-9]{1,2}[,][0-9]{1,13})|[0-9]{1}[,][0-9]{1,14}
```

But it didn't work.
Do you have any tips to help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```java
^[a-zA-Z]{3}(?=[^,]*,[^,]*$)\d(?:,?\d){14}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PxDYFT/2/).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z]{3}` - three ASCII letters
- `(?=[^,]*,[^,]*$)` - only one obligatory comma must be present further in the string
- `\d` - a digit
- `(?:,?\d){14}` - fourteen repetitions of an optional comma and a digit
- `$` - end of string.

Sample usage in Java to validate a string:

```java
Boolean isValid = text.matches("[a-zA-Z]{3}(?=[^,]*,[^,]*$)\\d(?:,?\\d){14}");
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I will define the answer as a solution asap